# How do you bake a deployment in a release pipeline stage?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to ensure that my deployment has baked for X hours in the current stage before it is deployed to the next. I was reading about post-deployment gates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops#define-a-gate-for-a-stage). I don't think these gates are the best way to ensure that the deployment has baked.

> For post-deployment gates, the delay would be the maximum of the time taken for the deployed app to reach a steady operational state, the time taken for execution of all the required tests on the deployed stage, and the time it takes for incidents to be logged after the deployment.

If the deployed app reaches a healthy state, then would the gate be opened to move to the next?

Or if its always going to wait X hours, if I want my build to bake for 4 hours, but it took 1 hour to deploy it, then it wouldn't bake completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a gate with delay

[image]

Asumming you have some healt check implemented in your app, it will make a request to a health check after 4 hours delay.

Comment: @merhoo can you consider also upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?